# Can I use images from an arxiv paper (and some others) in my undergrad thesis?

Tags: thesis, copyright, arxiv, license

I want to use images (in their unaltered form) from some arXiv papers (and some other venues) in my undergraduate thesis.

For instance, here are the papers from which I'm considering using images:

**From Arxiv**

- [Dropout](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.0580.pdf)
- [Resnets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf)
- "Why does deep learning works so well?"
- "Visualizing and understanding Convolutional Networks"
- Image Denoising with Kernels Based on Natural Image Relations

**Not from Arxiv**

- ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks

I am citing the papers from which I am taking the images, but I'm not sure if citing these images is sufficient, is bad practice, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least four things to consider:

1. **Is it allowed by academic ethics?**

   Yes, if you cite appropriately and make it clear where the image came from.
2. **Is it allowed by copyright law?**

   Maybe.  You'll have to look at the license that the arXiv paper is released under.  If it is copyrighted and not under a license that allows reproduction, you may have to get permission from the copyright holder (could be the author, or a commercial publisher who published the paper.)  On the other hand, there could be fair-use laws in your jurisdiction that allow it; see  [Academic fair use and using publication images in your thesis](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/40173/academic-fair-use-and-using-publication-images-in-your-thesis?rq=1).  But that question is not strictly on-topic for this site, since it's more about law than academia.
3. **Is it acceptable under your university's thesis regulations?**

   You'll have to read them.
4. **Is it acceptable to your advisor?**

   Ask him or her.  Excessive use of material from outside sources, even if properly cited and permitted by copyright, may suggest that your thesis does not contain enough original work to merit a passing grade.

Comment: I would add to point 1): It is allowed by academic ethics as long as you are using the figure to make a point similar to the one made by the original paper. This means that you can use a figure from a paper to eg. illustrate the theory presented in said paper, but you cannot use it as random clip art. As an obvious example: Don't take one of the birds in the first paper, fig. 3 and use it for a thesis about toucan beaks.

Comment: Note that it is now easy to see if an arXiv paper has a Creative Commons license, it is listed under the PDF link (it used to be very tricky to extract this information!).